Querying Dynamic Content with Dataflow Gen2 MS Fabric
I have to query data from an API. The company that provided us with the API requested we not load the data all at once but instead use a filter on the URL to upload only a certain amount of data at a time.
I want to always load data from the past 6 weeks. But given that we will have this dataflow on a scheduled refresh, the 6 weeks window will change depending on the week.
I have setup the dataflow, and within the dataflow it works correctly. But I am not able to publish it, as it fails with the error "Dynamic datasources are not supported."
This is the power query M code I am using:
    BaseUrl = "https://www.website.com:1111/api/Name/search/week>=",
    CurrentWeek = Date.StartOfWeek( DateTime.LocalNow()),
    DateSixWeeksAgo = Date.AddDays(CurrentWeek, -42),
    YearSixWeeksAgo = Date.Year(DateSixWeeksAgo),
    WeekSixWeeksAgo = Date.WeekOfYear(DateSixWeeksAgo),
    DynamicUrl = BaseUrl & Text.From(YearSixWeeksAgo) & Text.From(WeekSixWeeksAgo),
    Source = Json.Document(Web.Contents(DynamicUrl))

I want to save the table into a lakehouse, but even the publishing is not working

You can't make the first argument to Web.Contents dynamic, but it accepts addition parameters where you can change the RelativePath or Query.
Chris Webb explains here: https://blog.crossjoin.co.uk/2016/08/16/using-the-relativepath-and-query-options-with-web-contents-in-power-query-and-power-bi-m-code/
eg
Web.Contents(
 "https://data.gov.uk/api",
 [
  RelativePath="3/action/package_search",
  Query=[q="cows"]
 ]
)

